# How to write a Query in SQL for Current Year Cost and Previous Year Cost?

Tags: sql

How to write a Query in SQL for available fields in a Single Table?

Year  |  Month  |  Current Year Cost  |  Previous Year Cost

Comment: Provide (1) sample data (2) desired results (3) and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one row per year and month, the typical method is `lag()`:

```
select Year, Month, Cost,
       lag(cost) over (partition by month order by year) as prev_cost
from t;
```